# Java cipher behaves diffrently on diffrent Envirements

Tags: java, encryption

i have coded a netty server-client system with encryption but if i use the programm on my laptop it dosent work, there is no error so i dont know where the problem is, My Encryption utils class:

```
public static ByteBuf decryptWithRSA(ByteBuf encrypted, PrivateKey mykey) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, mykey);
    return wrightbytes(encrypted.alloc().buffer(), cipher.doFinal(readbytes(encrypted))); 
}

public static ByteBuf encryptWithRSA(ByteBuf encrypted, PublicKey mykey) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, mykey);
    return wrightbytes(encrypted.alloc().buffer(), cipher.doFinal(readbytes(encrypted))); 
}






public static ByteBuf encryptWithAES(SecretKey key, ByteBuf message) throws Exception  {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    return wrightbytes(message.alloc().buffer(), cipher.doFinal(readbytes(message)));
}

public static ByteBuf dycryptWithAES(SecretKey key, ByteBuf message) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    return wrightbytes(message.alloc().buffer(), cipher.doFinal(readbytes(message)));
}

public static SecretKey generateAESKey(int size) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
     KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kgen.init(size);
        return kgen.generateKey();
}

private static ByteBuf wrightbytes(ByteBuf wright, byte[] data) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < data.length) {
        wright.writeByte(data[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return wright;
}

private static byte[] readbytes(ByteBuf buf) {
    int read = buf.readableBytes();
    byte[] data = new byte[read];
    int i = buf.readerIndex();
    while (i < read) {
        data[i] = buf.readByte();
        i++;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Maybe anywone spots a bug i dident get? Thats for youre help

Comment: What kind of output are you getting versus what you expect when you run it on your laptop? Some sample data will help us understand the problem better.

Comment: I expect a encryped bytebuf but i get nothing at all the thread just stops

Comment: What do you mean by *it dosent work*? Describe what exactly happens.

Comment: `ByteBuf`? What is that? `Cipher.getInstance("AES");` and `Cipher.getInstance("RSA");` use defaults which risks non-portable behavior. There are many examples showing the correct way to do it.

Comment: @JamesKPolk a ByteBuf is from netty IO.

Comment: @mentallurg Is gets stuck on cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key); from the AES Cipher

Comment: What you mean by *gets stuck*? What happens exactly?

Comment: I dont know the thread just stops, no error is just doesn't continue after that method call